# three values in ValidatorOR Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1

I founded this in stackoverflow:

```
$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(new sfValidatorOr(
  array(
    new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('email', '!=', ''),
    new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('phone', '!=', ''),
  ),
  array(),
  array('invalid' => 'Campo obligatorio')
));
```

How can i add for this 3 values?

```
$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(new sfValidatorOr(
  array(
    new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('email', '!=', ''),
    new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('phone', '!=', ''),
    new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('yahooid', '!=', ''),
  ),
  array(),
  array('invalid' => 'Campo obligatorio')
));
```

this doesn't work. Then yahooid is always required... For example if i enter email and phone then valid is false, but if i enter  yahooid then this is ok.

Answer (score 0):

First, sfValidatorSchemaCompare() is for comparing **two fields**, not the value of a field. Use sfValidatorString instead.

For your need, sfValidatorCallback is my best shot:

```
$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(
        new sfValidatorCallback(array('callback' => array($this, 'fillAtLeastOne')))
);
```

Then

```
public function fillAtLeastOne($validator, $values)
{
  if (!$values['email']) && !$values['phone'] && !$values['yahooid'])
  {
    // All the field are empty / null, throw an error !
    throw new sfValidatorError($validator, 'Campo obligatorio.');
  }

  // is correct, return the clean values
  return $values;
}
```

The $values parameter contain all the values of the form, so it's easy to validate anything with a validatorCallback.